# How to send some count of POST/GET requests simultaneously?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, httprequest

I'm learning swift, trying to send 2 and more requests not one by one, but simultaneously. Is it possible with NSURLSession?

Comment: Are you sending requests to the same host? If so, it's the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` property of the associated session configuration that limits the number of connections.

Comment: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost) said it's 6 by default, but how I can send 6 requests in the same time, not just 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLSession is asynchronous which means it is sent on a different thread and can be run multiple at once.

This link explains and gives an example on how to handle the response back on the main thread etc:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

```
func sendRequest() {
    let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.url.com")

    dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
      data, response, error in
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          //Handle response
          if let error = error {
              //Error - handle 'error'              
              print(error.localizedDescription)
          } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
              if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                  //Success - handle 'data'
              }
          }
      }
    }

    dataTask?.resume()
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but how I can resume all of prepared requests simultaneously? Something like `[task1, task2].resumeAll()` = )

Comment: can you just keep a reference to each request and then do task1.resume(); task2.resume() etc.

Comment: I thought it's one by one, but I will be trying, thanks)

Comment: @osadchi If you think that I think you might not understand what async means. Async means you resume the 1., after that you resume the 2. And NSURLSession starts them at the same time (the first download/upload does not have to be finished for the second one to start - they are downloading in parallel (in fact, the second one can finish before the first one depending on many factors e.g. file size))

Comment: @HAS, ok, I got it, but if I type `task1.resume(); task2.resume();` first one be send earlier than second, but I need to send them both in one time.

Comment: But just a nanosecond or so (i.e. the time the processor needs to execute the code of `task1.resume()` which is really really fast (probably just creating a dispatch queue (or not even that) and kicking it off on that queue)